# VirtualBox disk resized, how to get last snapshot?

Tags: virtualbox, snapshot

I am setting a complex environment in a Linux Vbox, running under Windows 7. VBox version 4.3.15

I had to install a large number of items, with very complex dependencies... something that I do not want to do EVER AGAIN.

And I ran out of space.

So I found out how to use VBoxManage... to resize from 8 to 16 G

Tried

```
VBoxmanage modifyhd MyLinux.vdi --resize 16000
```

then tried to run `gparted`, but it did not show the new size. So I tried

```
VBoxManage clonehd MyLinux.vdi MyNewLinux.vdi --variant Standard
```

Then

```
VBoxmanage modifyhd MyNewLinux.vdi --resize 16000
```

then `gparted`... and everything worked perfectly.

Started my new machine... and to my unpleasant surprise found myself at a spot just before the first snapshot.

Is there any way to make it so I will have my resized machine working at the current location - latest snapshot or latest state ?

I thought about removing all previous snapshots from old machine, going through the resize process again - but I am afraid that I will lose my work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resize/clone your last differencing image. You can list them by `vboxmanage list hdds`.